# Excel, Match lookup array to ignore hidden rows

Tags: excel, match, aggregate-functions

NOTE: I'm using Excel 2016, don't have access to the good stuff in 365 :(

I'm trying to build a summary sheet at the moment. The idea is to filter a table, then have the summary formulas pick out the top 5 values in a given column.

To do this I'm trying to use the Large function in Aggregate which will help me ignore hidden rows while also allowing me to extract the nth largest value.

*From there I had thought to use match to find the row number of that value within the column so that I could also get text based values from the same row by assigning a column letter via Indirect.*

**^This is the crux of what I'm trying to do^**

The code looks like this at the moment... (Sales is column "R")

```
=MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,5,Table1[Sales],1),Table1[Sales],0)+62
```

Would then go be

```
=INDIRECT("N"&MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,5,Table1[Sales],1),Table1[Sales],0)+62)
```

Aggregate(14 = Large*

Aggregate(,5 = Ignore hidden rows*

The 62 there at the end is there as the data in the table starts on row 63 (making it more robust with row() is on my list but not there yet).

The issue I'm having is it seems the lookup array in the Match function `Table1[Sales]` isn't being filtered as the table is being filtered.

At least that's what the results I'm seeing are indicating to me as the row number I'm getting back isn't within the filtered table (I.e. Match is returning a hidden row number).

My question is if anyone has an idea about how make this so that only visible rows are considered within the array.

(If I've completely missed the mark with this and someone has a better idea about how to accomplish this goal (without having to resort to array functions) I'd be very grateful).

### Thanks!

Expected results

| row | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company A | 425 |
| 2 | Company B | 1500 |
| 4 | Company A | 1200 |
| 7 | Company C | 750 |
| 15 | Company B | 100 |
| 19 | Company A | 100 |

I'd be looking for the nth largest value in column B, say 1200 (second largest) in this example.

```
=MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,5,B:B,2),B:B,0)
=MATCH((1200),C:C,0))
=3
```

The expected result is Row 4, but because (again, it seems) the look-up array isn't excluding filtered/hidden rows, it is returning Row 3 instead.

I hope this is a bit clearer!

Comment: Add few data sample and expected output so that we can understand clearly. If you have **Excel 365** then it would be easier. What is your excel version?

Comment: @Harun24HR, I updated the original question with the expected vs actual results, I hope it's more clear